# Custom List in java

Tags: java, list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrivalsList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    public int first() {
        return this.get(0);
    }

    public int last() {
        return this.get(this.size() - 1);
    }

}
```

Is this a good way of creating a custom list? Or is there any other, better way to do this?

Comment: Use the provided one: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getFirst--

Comment: No. Extending from ArrayList is not a good idea, and you should [program on interfaces rather than concrete implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). Write your static utility method to get the first / last elements of any list if you find using get() is so difficult. Or create your own class **using** a list, rather than extending it.

Comment: List and Custom List could confused so ask question properly

Comment: Re-Inventing the wheel is the bad idea....

Comment: In general: When you derive from a class and (only) add public methods to the derivative, it is most likely not a good idea. There are exceptions of course, e.g applying the `LayerSuperType`pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand as well what do you mean by "custom list".

But in your code, it seems you want to retrieve only the first and the last integer from the List. 
If you want to perform only this two operations, a Queue would be better than an ArrayList in term of performance.

Obviously, if you have to deal with a limited number of data, the solutions are practically equivalent.

Comment: I will use it for more operations. I just wondered if this is a good way of doing it. I am developing an app for retrieving bus arrivals in my town and i wanted it to get the first and last arrival for now.

Thank you :)